# Switch entrando no case errado

Tags: c++, switch

Estou tentando resolver o problema do Uri 1038 utilizando do `switch`, aparentemente os valores estão se misturando, o Item 3 por exemplo, multiplicando por 2 (5 x 2) retorna o valor 3. O que estou fazendo de errado aqui?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, q;

    float valor;

    cin >> i >> q;

    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            valor = 4.00*q;
        case 2:
            valor = 4.50*q;
        case 3:
            valor = 5.00*q;
        case 4:
            valor = 2.00*q;
        case 5:
            valor = 1.50*q;
    }

    cout << "Total: R$" << valor;
}
```

[image: Dados de entrada]

Comment: Acho que o `switch` está executando sem *pausas*. Faltaram alguns *breaks* no seu código. Veja em [switch statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch#Explanation).

Comment: Você está se squecendo dos `break`'s

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Caraca, eu estudei isso ontem e esqueci do break mesmo. Mas mesmo agora com os breaks certinho em cada condição continua dando o mesmo resultado.

Edit: fechei o VS e abri o projeto de novo e agora está rodando ok, obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema neste código é a falta de `break` em cada `case` do `switch`, já que esta construção todos podem ser executados, entenda ele como `um` goto` e não um mecanismo de decisão, ele pula para o primeiro que é válido, depois só não continua executando os demais se você explicitamente manda quebrar. Aproveitei para melhorar um pouco o código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int item, qtde;
    float valor;
    cin >> item >> qtde;
    switch (item) {
    case 1:
        valor = 4.00;
        break;
    case 2:
        valor = 4.50;
        break;
    case 3:
        valor = 5.00;
        break;
    case 4:
        valor = 2.00;
        break;
    case 5:
        valor = 1.50;
        break;
    }
    cout << "Total: R$" << valor * qtde;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2B0Hum). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pokldjtf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Switch.cpp).

Tem um jeito melhor de fazer isto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int item, qtde;
    cin >> item >> qtde;
    array<float, 5> valores = { 4.00, 4.50, 5.00, 2.00, 1.50 };
    cout << "Total: R$" << valores[item - 1] * qtde;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/q9GLlh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/worplgow-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/NoSwitch.cpp).

Comment: Obrigado Maniero e Anderson Carlos, realmente boiei no break, estudei ontem e esqueci dos coitados no Switch. 

Ainda não peguei muito Array e não arrisquei fazer, mas vendo agora sua solução com ela realmente é bem melhor e simples, obrigadão!